# Selecting points with specific attributes in ArcMap ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select

This is the example of my problem:

[image: Selection problem]

I need to collect points that are within polygons. There are some polygons that contain more than one point. In this case I need to select one point with a specific attribute which represents the polygon. For example: There are two points in selected polygon ("NAZ_LAU1" = Kladno) and I want a point with a higher "POCET_OBYV" to be selected. 

 
Since I work with a large dataset and do not have any Python skills, I need to do it in ModelBuilder.

Comment: Do you have Advanced license? Then Intersect - Sort (by POCET_OBYV field) - Delete Identical - Join - Select by attributes should work

Comment: When you say "I need to collect points that are within polygons" and looking at your screenshot when you have 2 or more points in a polygon you want the point with the higher pocet_obyv and _for all other areas_ where there is just one point you want to simply return that single point?